# Giving profile updates to a potential supervisor

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, advisor, communication

I had been interviewed for a research-based master's position two weeks ago. Since then, I have submitted two papers to top-tier venues in my field.

Additionally, a few days before the interview, I had taken up an industrial role. However, this never came up in the interview. As far as I know, the advisor isn't aware of these updates.

My question is, should I send a mail to the potential supervisor with these updates, given that I will almost certainly be attending if accepted (almost, since I am waiting to hear back from a few other programs)? Or should I wait for the decision without further communication?

Comment: Surely you have discussed your papers being almost ready for submission during your interview? Having them submitted now is a minor update. If they were accepted  it would be worth informing the potential advisor. I don't see how bringing up your industry position could help your application.

Comment: No, the papers were not discussed at all. The projects were just mentioned on my SoP as "in progress". That was about three months ago.

Comment: That was a mistake on your part. I'd expect an interviewee to mention that they intend to submit two papers within the next month. Anyway, what is the application process? Do you apply directly to the advisor or is the application to a graduate school? In the former case, I might send a quick and modest note to the advisor. In the latter case, I probably wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two worries. The first is that "submission" isn't really an accomplishment, though finishing up on the work might be.

The second, a bit more serious, is that having accepted another position, you might seem to be less interested in the program you interviewed for.

I'd definitely let the second slide and only mention the first if you get some positive feedback on the submissions.

However, a note that you are making progress on some current work and nearing the end is a positive thing that you might mention if another opportunity to communicate arises.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful advice!

Answer (score 0):

If somehow you inform your potential supervisor about these updates and also your industrial role, it might be helpful. It is better than feeling sorry later on.

My son applied for Masters (which later on led to Ph.D) but he got a rejection email. He sent an email to the graduate school about his training and industrial work. He was interviewed again and got acceptance.